# How does this circuit read 4-20mA current loop input through Op-amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement, 4-20ma

I am a software guy working on coding a control system on a board whose hardware designers are all gone. While i have got everything else working, there is one piece (a 4-20 mA current loop input) which i am not clear enough to start coding for. Attached is the picture.

[image: Inputs Subsystem]

J12 (pin 2 is not used) is the input from potentiometer. I have this working by reading P1.3 in my code (0-3 V mapped to 0-1023 range via 10-bit ADC). However i don't understand the circuit from J11. Am I supposed to read P1.0? What is the voltage range to which the 4-20 mA is mapped to? I need to know this since i can then configure my MCU (a Silabs c8051F850) appropriately for the 10-bit ADC.

**Edit 30/6/17:** Multisim simulation of relevant circuit (pointed out by @jonk) below

[image]

Comment: The usual "4-20 mA" circuit has a power supply biasing it, but this one just has a two-pin connector (J11) shown, with GND and a resistor to GND.   Something is missing.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean. The attached snippet is part of a full schematic of a board. J11 is actually connected to a 2-lead "4-20mA" current source from some sensor subsystem (testing is done with something like this: https://www.amazon.com/4-20mA-Simulator-Generator-PLC-Instrumentation/dp/B00NUBHJR8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1473262051&sr=8-1&keywords=4-20ma+signal+generator).

Comment: A "4-20mA" sensor is powered through the same two wires that it delivers its sense data through.   If this connector is NOT powered, does that mean the schematic is of a sensor, and not of a controller?

Comment: No, the schematic is of the control board. The 4-20mA has its own power source to generate current. The current is input into our board using the J11 connector. But i still don't understand the schematic. Please see my answer below to "jonk" for my source of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

120E is just \$120\Omega\$. If you look at J11, it's putting a \$120\Omega\$ resistor in the current loop. So this means, at \$4mA\$ the drop will be about \$480mV\$ and at \$20mA\$ the drop will be about \$2.4V\$. This voltage is applied to the (+) input of U4A via a negligibly small \$10\Omega\$ resistor, so the opamp then attempts to change its output so that the (-) input equals that input voltage. (It *follows* the input.)

You get to decide how you want to handle these things. If there is no current, then the output will be close to \$0V\$ and you may care about that. If there is something near to \$4mA\$ drive, then you will see about \$500mV\$ present. If \$20mA\$ then near to \$2.4V\$. All within range of your converter, I suspect. That's what P1.0 should *see*.

---

LATE EDIT:

The relevant circuit for your \$4-20\:\textrm{mA}\$ subcircuit is the following (and not as you diagrammed it):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdLNn6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've kept the capacitors in place so that all the details are present and can be used to double-check my work. But you can ignore them for the purposes of figuring out where to put the meter.

One lead of the meter should be attached to ground. This means anywhere that's convenient. Note that J11.1 is attached to ground. So you could use that pin or anything directly connected to it for this purpose. You could use the ground end of \$R_{15}\$, if that was easier for you. You could use the (-) supply pin of the LM358 if that was easier. If you have a question about some "convenient" bit of metal available to you, then just measure the Ohms from that spot to J11.1. If it is very close to \$0\:\Omega\$, then chances are you are okay using that convenient spot.

The other lead of the meter should be attached to the place of interest. In this case, I think you want any pin or end of a device that is attached to P1.0. This could be the non-ground end of \$C_{18}\$ or the non-ground end of \$R_{21}\$ or the output pin of the LM358 (pin 1) or even its (-) input pin (pin 2.) If you have any question about which end is which, just check again by measuring from the point you aren't sure about to J11.1. If it is very close to \$0\:\Omega\$, then it is NOT the correct end and you need to consider the other end of it as the one you probably want.

Comment: @RamanathanR: The circuit isn't too complicated. But still simpler might have just used the resistor (it's not a floating input situation) and skipped the opamp, feeding the developed voltage directly to your micro ADC input (with a zener and a few diodes and resistors as input protection.) Or just used an opto isolator.

Comment: Thank you.
I got it to work by reading P1.0. 4-20mA over 120ohms gives me 480-2400mv. I configured ADC to range between 0-2.4v and adjusted the lower bound of 10-bit ADC from 0-1023 to 205-1023 in code.

However i still don't understand the schematic. Its seems pin1 of J11 is connected to ground and pin2 of J11 also seems to go to ground over 120ohms R15. I am not seeing how it connects to the op-amp U4A whose output is what i am reading.

Comment: There's a lot of extra _stuff_ there that may be a bit confusing. Remove \$C_9\$ from your vision, for example. Just get rid of it. And ignore the ground symbol for a moment, too. Then I think you might see the _loop_ that goes from pin 1 and through the \$120\Omega\$ resistor and then to pin 2. This connects to an external thing that is trying to push between 4mA and 20mA through that loop. Doing so causes the resistor to possess a voltage across it. Grounding one side doesn't change that fact. But then the other side will have a voltage referred to that. Which then goes to the opamp input.

Comment: I see it now. Loop circuit from J11-pin1 goes right, down, left and up over R15 to J11-pin2. But just before reaching J11-pin2 the voltage is fed to the op-amp over R14.

Comment: So what is the function of the other op-amp U4B connected to J12-pin2? My guess is that it switches the direction of the potentiometer i.e. when pot is connected to J12-pins1,3,4 you are in ascending direction whereas when pot is connected to J12-pins1,2,4 you are in descending direction.

Comment: @RamanathanR: Looks like a follower that accepts an input voltage without much of any protection. Maybe it was used to copy the other signal, jumpering pin 2 to pin 2? I don't know, though.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this but i would appreciate your suggestions on this problem. I did my simulation (circuit diagram attached in edits to OP) and do see 4-20mA giving me 507-2426mV in the simulation. However on the actual board i don't get the corresponding ADC values. At 20mA i should see about 1023 ADC but see around 615 ADC only. The ADC at 4mA seems to be more or less ok. Note that my ADC range is [0-1023] and VREF range is [0-2400mV]. So it seems like my understanding of the circuit is wrong. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @RamanathanR There's nothing in the circuit to tell me what your \$V_{REF}\$ is. You should be measuring about 2.4 V at 20 mA and you say that you *are* measuring that about right. Same with 4mA. So there is nothing wrong. The opamp just follows this. So P1.0 should see those same voltages and you should be able to measure P1.0, too, to verify that. The rest is going on inside your micro. And I have no visibility there. If you are seeing the analog voltages you should see, the rest is entirely about software and its use of the internal registers and selections you make inside.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear. The simulation shows the correct voltages (assuming my simulated circuit above is right and i am taking the voltage difference across the correct points). On the actual board itself i am not able to measure the voltages to validate the simulation. But given my configured VREF and ADC range, i expect a certain value which is what is off by almost 50% (at the higher end of mA). I am not getting the right voltages and hence the right ADC values at the higher end of the mA.....Cont'd

Comment: .....: I have tested my MCU with different VREF ranges (eg. [0-2400mV] and [0-3300mV] and in all cases i don't get the right ADC values (again at the higher end of mA). While i am looking for possible bugs in my code (am almost sure there are no problems in configuring the MCU :-), i just wanted some expert to validate that my understanding of the relevant circuit is correct.

Comment: @RamanathanR I've never encountered a board where I couldn't stick a probe down onto, say, pin 14, and make a voltage measurement. Are you saying it is impossible to measure P1.0 directly with a meter?

Comment: Almost...but that is what i am trying to do. It is all SMT, the MCU is in a QSOP24 pin package, all the pins are not broken out and i have only one board :-) Hence i am being extremely careful in attempting to probe the circuit at various points on the PCB.

Comment: @RamanathanR I think you need to actually get a measurement off of that pin: SMT or otherwise. Just be careful. I've had to work with worse (try BGA, sometime.) There are tiny "grabber clips" which are cheap and work well in many circumstances. But if you don't have them, just set up your ground lead somewhere safe and only hold the + lead, with a needle tip, onto the pin when you are comfortable and stable and can read the result.

Comment: One question. As you can see from my simulation circuit, i am taking the voltage drop between P1.0  (coming off of R3) and the other side of R1 resistor. Is that correct?

Comment: @RamanathanR I don't see \$R_1\$. But I do see \$R_{21}\$. If you mean \$R_{21}\$, then sure. Measure the voltage across that resistor. (But you should be able to put the ground lead of the meter on a more convenient point.)

Comment: I was talking about the 2nd simulation circuit. "XMM1" is the multimeter which is connected to the appropriate points. The resistor mapping between the two diagrams are as follows; R15=R1, R14=R2, R21=R3.

Comment: @RamanathanR That's an odd location for a multimeter and besides that your circuit is NOT representative of the original circuit section. For example, if it were representative then your \$R_1\$ would have one end tied to ground (and it does not.)

Comment: @RamanathanR I've created a new schematic of the subcircuit for you and discussed how to take the relevant measurement. If this measurement turns out to be approximately as expected, then your problem is in your software or in your understanding of what your microcontroller is telling you.

Comment: This is great! Thank you and i really appreciate all your help. Will definitely try it out and let you know.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back earlier. The final resolution was that the actual value of R15 on the physical board was 100 Ohms and NOT 120 Ohms as shown in my original schematic. Modifying the code appropriately solved my problem. Lesson learnt here is not to assume schematic values as gospel but to always double-check with the physical board, particularly for prototypes :-)